# How to replace a string in sqlite depending on some condition

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite, replace

I have a field 'amount' which contains number with thousand separators. e.g 1,200.00

I want to replace ',' comma with nothing. from `1,200.00` to `1200.00`.

I have used replace function and it worked. But, the problem is for germany '.' dot acts as a thousand separator. e.g 1,200.00 is 1.200,00 in germany. So I want to replace dot over here and ','comma with dot.

means i want to change 1.200,00 to 1200.00

And I want to do it with one query only.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own function to do something like that, unless maybe you have the nationality of the number stored in the database as well. Take a look at the documentation for creating custom functions. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html

Comment: Hi I did in this way ....update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(replace(substr(FIELD_NAME, 1,length(FIELD_NAME)-3),',',''),'.','') || '.' || substr(FIELD_NAME,-2)